# Set web browser (or other program) to use specific network

Tags: networking, vpn, local-area-network

my PC is connected to 3 different networks: 2 different LAN connections and a VPN connection.

when i am connected to the vpn, i cannot browse to the LAN intranet as the DNS is all going through the vpn and it cannot see the domains on the LAN.

Is there a way to set firefox/chrome/etc to use a specific connection, so that i don't have to disconnect from vpn to get to the other intranets?

Answer (score 1):

The network routing table determines how your connections are utilized.

You potentially have a subnet conflict between the LAN and your VPN.  Change your LAN to a subnet outside of your VPN.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a DNS issue, 
Or your VPN client may not allow split tunneling which means you will be unable to access your local resource in any way not just through the browser.
Or it could be that you are using a proxy server that is forcing web traffic through your VPN connection